# How to track when user verified their email by clicking on the verification link?

Tags: apex, community

I use the [System.UserManagement.sendAsyncEmailConfirmation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_UserManagement.htm) method to send emails with a validation link. Now I want to execute some logic exactly when they click that link. Or at least when the User Verified Email becomes true.

[image]
  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

The status is being kept in the TwoFactorMethodsInfo sObject. You need to grant "Manage Two-Factor Methods through API" / "Manage Two-Factor Methods through the UI" permission first to see this object.